# Why is Visual Basic 6 Packaging and Deployment Wizard system freezing with no message why

Tags: deployment, vb6, packaging

I have amended an old VB6 program, adding new images and making fairly simple code changes. When I come to creating the CAB file, the P&D Wizard freezes halfway through and gives no reason why. It could be looking for a file, can't find it and is just looping.I have tried checking existence of files but so far have found nothing.
Does anyone have any good ideas? I would be very grateful for help with this. Is there any other way of creating a CAB file?

Comment: Does running it as Administrator make any difference? How far through the process do you get (on which step does it freeze)?

Comment: Thanks for interest.  I do run it as Administrator. I can't tell how far it has got as it freezes with no message about why. I'm going to try a system called iexpress.exe which someone has recommended.

Comment: You might need to watch it in Process Monitor to find out what problem it is having.